# read DONE_IN_PROC

Tags: sql-server

If I understand correctly, with stored procedure result is also returned a message called [DONE_IN_PROC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd340553.aspx)

> Fragment From MSDN:
>
> ... SET NOCOUNT ON eliminates the sending of DONE_IN_PROC messages to the
> client for each statement in a stored procedure.

Is there a way to access this message somehow in Management Studio after executing stored procedure and read i.e. number of rows affected.

(I am asking out of curiosity and I know there are other ways to get number of rows affected)

Comment: Management studio uses this to show the `(X row(s) affected)` message in the messages tab. So just look at that tab. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, I wonder if there is a way to grab this message as an object. If it's returned from the procedure, I expect it to be accessible somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Certain (if not all) Database APIs make the TDS layer's DONE_IN_PROC message accessible. If ODBC is the chosen Database API, see the  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130812.aspx discussion about SQLRowCount, SQLGetStmtAttr, and NOCOUNT.

Answer (score -1):

Late to the party but are you just after the int from the message?

```
create proc delme as
begin
    select * from sys.databases
end
go

set nocount on
go    

exec delme  --returns "(7 row(s) affected)" on the message channel
select @@ROWCOUNT  --returns 7
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but this is not what I am asking for. I am rather wondering if there is a way to read this DONE_IN_PROC token. ROWCOUNT is just a part of this token.